# Variable assignment during re-coding loop

Tags: r, for-loop, variable-assignment

I am importing survey data from a CSV file in R, and I want to use a for-loop to reassign periods in the cells to "NA". For just one survey item, I have to do this:

```
survey$q1a <- recode(survey$q1a, "'.'=NA") # csv column a
survey$q1a <- as.numeric(as.character(survey$q1a))
```

where the `q1a` is the column title in the CSV file, and refers to question 1, part a (I have 137 columns). So, in order to make a for-loop, I need to be able to do something like this:

```
for (n in 1:31){
    survey$qna <- recode(survey$qna, "'.'=NA") # csv column n
    survey$qna <- as.numeric(as.character(survey$qna))
}
```

31 items have a part a, which means I need to do this from `survey$q1a` to `survey$q31a`. For the sake of simplicity, it is best to keep my columns in the `qna` format (ironically). I have never really used R, but I have experience with Python and C, and I know that I could often use the `%` with `%s` operators in those languages to achieve similar goals.

Is there a way to do this in R without changing how my variable/column labeling system?

Comment: `read.csv(... , na.strings = '.')`

Comment: Thanks! Boy, have I been doing this wrong.